# Strange rendering of word "slang" as sh=lang

Tags: support, edits, title

Perhaps it's due to using the mobile site? [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48877728/812183) ([screen for <10k](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEIRO.png))  renders like this on the homepage:

[image: screenshot of homepage]

Browser is Chrome on Android:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G935V Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.137 Mobile Safari/537.36`

Could also be a ninja edit and caches?

Comment: Ninja edit within grace period?

Comment: The author probably just hit the `=` key instead of the backspace key

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question was posted as you saw it. Then edited a minute later. Then deleted 4 minutes later.

Source: http://shouldiblamecaching.com